# My old boss contacted me, they want me to do work for them again on the side

Tags: salary

I live in montreal and had been working for a year at a company until June 2016.

While I was there I greatly impressed them with my Motion Design and Video Editing abilities and allowed them to make trailers of their games of much higher quality than before.

I had been contacted a few weeks ago, offering essentially my old job back (I refused, currently updating my portfolio and hoping for bigger challenges), and today, I was contacted again, this time asking for me to do exclusively trailers for them again. They will call me tomorrow to discuss it.

I had a salary of 15$ per hour while I worked there as a 2D Artist, and I checked, the median salary for Motion Designer, the job they want me to do, which is about 23$.

I'd like to ask for 25$, but I had people advising me to ask for as much as 40$ per hour since it's contract based and since they came to me, I have the big end of the stick.

Basically, I'd like to have anyone's input. What should I do? How should I do it? What should I say on the phone when we discuss the conditions? Is it too greedy of me to just go and ask about twice the salary I earnt while I was there before?

Comment: Not an answer since I don't know any of the details of Canadian tax code, etc; but if you're contracting the rate you charge should not just be the equivalent of a salaried employees hourly pay but include the value of all benefits you get working for a company and whatever additional taxes you need to pay for being self employed.  the latter are normally more than what an employee has to pay because you're being taxed as a both a worker and a business.

Comment: VTC advice question. With some minor [edit]s to focus on ways to determine a contracting salary or just the conditions to set in this scenario this would be more focused on a core question and on-topic. Note that there are a few questions covering the salary aspect here and on [freelancing.se].

Answer (score 9):

Roughly speaking, charging company $x/hr on a contract is the same as getting half that as an employee. Employees get statutory holidays paid (I think there are 14 a year in Quebec?), vacation of at least 4%, perhaps more, sick days, benefits, paid training, and are paid even when there's nothing to do. Contractors get none of that and may not even be paid for all the hours they work - if you tell someone a trailer is 10 hours work, you will almost certainly only be able to bill them 10 hours even if it ends up taking you 20 - especially if it's your mistake that causes the extra time. And you need to spend time doing accounting, preparing invoices, company tax returns, and so on. You need to kick in both parts of EI and CPP, or perhaps your hours spent on this won't count towards EI and CPP (you need professional advice on this, and you have to pay for that sort of thing out of your bill rate too.)

So if your salary was $15 you would need to bill them a minimum of $30/hr to be equivalent. Do you want to be equivalent? Some people would think you need more than you used to make, to make it worth your while. I don't know what you'd be doing with your evenings and weekends if you weren't moonlighting for your old employer. Watching TV pays $0/hr. Drinking with your buddies pays a negative amount per hour, because you have to pay for your drinks.

Will this work make you better? Will it make you better known? Could you end up a trailer-maker for all kinds of shops? Is that something you want? Is doing it a step forward? Will it jeopardize your "day job"? Will it cause tension in your home life? Will you spend more on takeout food or paying for services (taxis, cleaning service, dog walker) because you have less time? Only you can juggle all of that and figure out what you need to get to make this worth your while.

The marvelous thing is, once you've found this number, life is good. Say it's $Y. If you ask for $Y + 10%, and they say ok, you are happy. They can even work you down a little. But if they can't get above $Y, if their limit is less, you can walk away without the slightest regret or upset. You know it's not worth it for you for that money. And if you get it, you get it. And you're doing something that's worth your while.

Answer (score 2):

A $15/hour employee costs more than $15/hour, depending on your tax jurisdiction, benefits, etc. It's also irrelevant. The question is what the market will bear. You are a known quantity that produces a known, quality result. That's valuable. And if you're willing to walk away, there's no downside in asking for too much.

Comment: Yep, ask high, negotiate down

Comment: youre right, I really don't care to walk away from the job so I might as well make it worht my while